# Does Chocolatey support post-install commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget, chocolatey

When writing my own choco packages, how can I have them execute command immediately after the software is installed? I don't want to pass these commands to the installer, but want them to run after the installer completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chocolateyInstall.ps1 is just a PowerShell script, so you have maximum flexibility. You can do things prior and after the installation.